# Adding a scrollbar to JList , JList being added to a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

i am having a list which i want to populate dynamically , hence scrollbar is required. I have added a scrollbar to list. The problem is that when i try to add the list to a panel. the scrollbar becomes visible on the list but they dont work even when the list's element gets bigger in size.

```
JPanel p4=new JPanel();
Container c=getContentPane();
myList=new JList(model);
myList.setVisibleRowCount(5);
myList.setFixedCellWidth(200);

p4.add(new JScrollPane(myList,ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
     ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS));
c.add(p4);
```

Comment: should work as expected (see @Robin's SSCCE) - something wrong with the code you are not showing ...

Answer (score 2):

Works just fine here. I used the [SplitPaneDemo.java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/SplitPaneDemoProject/src/components/SplitPaneDemo.java) file for this [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), and stripped away all the unnecessary stuff

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class SplitPaneDemo extends JPanel {
  private JList<String> list;
  private String[] imageNames = { "Bird", "Cat", "Dog", "Rabbit", "Pig", "dukeWaveRed",
      "kathyCosmo", "lainesTongue", "left", "middle", "right", "stickerface"};
  public SplitPaneDemo() {
    setLayout( new BorderLayout(  ) );

    list = new JList<>(imageNames);
    list.setSelectionMode( ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION );
    list.setSelectedIndex( 0 );

    add( new JScrollPane(list) );
  }

  /**
   * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
   * this method should be invoked from the
   * event-dispatching thread.
   */
  private static void createAndShowGUI() {

    //Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("SplitPaneDemo");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    SplitPaneDemo splitPaneDemo = new SplitPaneDemo();
    frame.getContentPane().add(splitPaneDemo);

    //Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
    //creating and showing this application's GUI.
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        createAndShowGUI();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar question here: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818163)

I don't think the answer is the same in your case though. Maybe the problem happens when you add stuff to the list; you could try doing:

```
myList.revalidate();
```

after it changes.

Comment: **no** - revalidate is **never** needed after a model change (provided the model complies to its notification contract)